# Eclipse class template

Tags: java, eclipse

I want each class of a given package in Eclipse to be filled with:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MainJWSPLIN {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    }
}
```

...I mean when I create a new class I want it to have those contents already.

Comment: Look in `Window -> Preferences > Java > Code Style > Code Templates`.

Comment: Ok... I knew I should look for the solution there... but where should I paste the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option you have is to do it with [Editor Templates](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-editor-templates.htm&cp=1_2_6). But in this case you will have to manually type the short alias (e.g., buffreader) to insert this text.

[image: editor template]

The other option is to use [Code Templates](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fcodestyle%2Fref-preferences-code-templates.htm&cp=1_4_2_0_2_1) which is more related to your question as you can associate them to action such as creating a new class by the New Class wizards to generate code.

[image: code template]